# Multiple Factorials

Tags: python, function, loops

I am currently in a class learning how to use Python 2.7.11 and I am being asked to write a function that will print the first n factorials, in reverse order. It is preferred that we do this using a for loop inside of a function, could really use some help. Thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service. Come back with a specific problem you are having. You can also just search your problem on Stack Overflow and find it.

Comment: "Please do my homework for me" Please ask a question including your research, including any relevant code/error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already tried and you cannot think of a way because you are new to programming.

First you can think how it is done by hand then try to see what you learned in the class. Loop will help to repeat and if statements to take decisions. Every language will have this basic blocks which helps you to do anything programmatically. Python does not have a "do while loop" like other languages, which make sense because its redundant.

Try to think of your own come up with the answer it will help you to learn.